# IEnumerable.Any() and .Count() throwing TargetInvocationException even though I'm checking if null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**Background**

I'm using LINQ to SQL to get information from a database. I recently changed the query to work with an updated version of the database where I switched a string column to a bit column. However, when I look at an older version of the database, it crashes.

Instead of crashing, I want the program to open with an empty list so the user can change the settings to look in the right place next time. If it crashes upon opening, they can't change the settings.

**Code**

The LINQ query runs fine, but if I try to check if it's empty using `.Any()` or `.Count()`, or I try to cast it as a list, it crashes and throws a `TargetInvocationException` exception, with the inner exception being `NullReferenceException`. However, it's not null.

```
IEnumerable<Airplane> propPlanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p =>
    p != null &&
    p.IsPropeller == true // used to be p.IsPropeller == "YES" 
);

List<Airplane> propPlanesList = new List<Airplane>();

if (propPlanes != null && _dataContext.Airplanes != null)  // expression is always true
{
    if (propPlanes.Any())                     // throws TargetInvocationException 
    {
        propPlanesList = propPlanes.ToList(); // would throwTargetInvocationException
    }
}

return propPlanesList ;
```

How can I check if there's nothing coming back from the query?

Stack trace for `TargetInvocationException`:

```
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(Type type, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(Object[] arguments)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ClaytonSystem.App.Main() in \\pcppnasw02\users$\cclayto\My Documents\Work\GitHub\c\V2\WPFDataGrid\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Stack trace for inner exception (`NullReferenceException`):

```
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invoke)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ClaytonSystem.MainWindow.GetCheckTasks() in \\pcppnasw02\users$\cclayto\My Documents\Work\GitHub\c\V2\WPFDataGrid\Window1.xaml.cs:line 611
   at ClaytonSystem.MainWindow.ListCheckTasks() in \\pcppnasw02\users$\cclayto\My Documents\Work\GitHub\c\V2\WPFDataGrid\Window1.xaml.cs:line 751
   at ClaytonSystem.MainWindow..ctor() in \\pcppnasw02\users$\cclayto\My Documents\Work\GitHub\c\V2\WPFDataGrid\Window1.xaml.cs:line 129
```

Comment: You probably have a "null" entry in your _dataContext.Airplanes. Did you verify that?

Comment: Like a `p != null` in the query? I tried that and there wasn't any difference. I also just checked `_dataContext.Airplanes != null` and there wasn't any difference either. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Ok then, is `IsPropeller` a `Property` with a `get` that might refer to a null object?

Comment: The properties are auto-generated by Visual Studio. It's defined as `[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_IsPropeller", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]`

Comment: A linq-to-sql table won't yield `null` items. Your error is weird. Please dump the full stack trace to the question, it might help.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, done.

Comment: Please provide generated SQL statement, You can get it with SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this problem is caused by the fact that you have changed `string` reference type to `bool` value type in your model and data base is not updated yet. Linq-To-Sql expects that `IsPropeller` property will always have its value and blows up when it cannot convert retrieved "YES"/"NO" `string` to `bool`.

Error seems to occur at the moment when Linq-To-Sql tries to create your entity instance.

Although I don't know real answer to this question as you are using Linq-To-Sql not as intended, here are things you could try:

1) Remove `p != null` check as this can not be directly translated to SQL and might causes reading all data records and doing filtering on client side;

2) Add extra null check on `IsPropeller` property to fool Linq-To-Sql perform `null` checks:

```
p.IsPropeller != null && p.IsPropeller == true
```

3) If this does not help, change `IsPropeller` type to `bool?` and add extra `null` check:

```
p.IsPropeller.HasValue && p.IsPropeller == true
```

4) Try to determine value by converting value before comparison so it works both with `bit` and `varchar`:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.IsPropeller == "true"
```